# Recursion function failed in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursion, anonymous-recursion

I am using a recursion function to convert my menus in a tree. The array I got from the database is:

```
array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [nav_group_id] => 1 
    [entity_id] => 1 
    [parent] => 0 
    [name] => Meter Reading 
    [link] => # ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [nav_group_id] => 1 
    [entity_id] => 2 
    [parent] => 0 
    [name] => Parameterization 
    [link] => # ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( 
    [nav_group_id] => 1 
    [entity_id] => 3 
    [parent] => 0 
    [name] => View Reports 
    [link] => # ) 
  [3] => stdClass Object ( 
    [nav_group_id] => 1 
    [entity_id] => 4 
    [parent] => 0 
    [name] => Management & Control 
    [link] => # ) 
  [4] => stdClass Object ( 
    [nav_group_id] => 1 
    [entity_id] => 5 
    [parent] => 1 
    [name] => Billing Data 
    [link] => # ) 
  [5] => stdClass Object ( 
    [nav_group_id] => 1 
    [entity_id] => 6 
    [parent] => 1 
    [name] => MDI Billing Data
    [link] => # )
```

I am calling a recursive function by passing the above mentioned array to this function:

```
$this->parseAndPrintTree('0',$navigation_all);
//die();   (issue here)
```

Now if I use `die();` after this function it shows the correct menu, and if don't use `die();` the page fails to load and gives this error:

> Content Encoding Error
>      The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression."

...and shows no output. Here is my recursive function:

```
function parseAndPrintTree($root, $tree) 
{
    $return = array();
    if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) 
    {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($tree as $child => $parent) 
        {
            if($parent->parent == $root) 
            {                    
                unset($tree[$child]);
                echo '<li>'.$parent->name;
                $this->parseAndPrintTree($parent->entity_id, $tree);
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "fix" of putting `die();` after the function is not conclusive as to what the problem is. That is, there's no guarantee that your error is really coming from your recursive function.

Comment: @nickb but my code is clear please, point out if there is any problem in it..
i donot think there is infinite recursion taking place

Comment: @nickb but my code is clear please, point out if there is any problem in it..
i donot think there is infinite recursion taking place...

Also i am very sure that the problem is in recursion function because if i didn't use it code runs fine

Comment: Do you have compression turned on in the config? I.E. `$config['compress_output'] = TRUE;`? Try setting it to false if it is.

Comment: @Bulk u said right man!!!!!!!!!!
i changed $config['compress_output'] to false and all done...

but i also want to compress my output as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I seem to be on to something I'll post this as an answer.

When you have gzip compression enabled, you cannot output anything to the browser before the compression functions have a chance to output, which Codeigniter automatically does near the end of its execution stack. In your recursion function you have an echo which is what is doing this output.

The best way to fix this is to convert this function in to a [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html) function, and then put the call to this function inside a view file rather than a controller or library which is where I assume it is now.

Comment: what if i want to returned the tree output to controller instead of using echo i used a variable $arraged.='ul' etc etc but it results in same errored output

Comment: Are you then passing that variable to a view to echo it there?

Comment: yeah i am doing the same .....
But not successful please, help me how to format this variable and pass it to view

Comment: instead of using echo i want to add the output to some buffer type variable, then i want to return it to where the function is called and then pass it to view.....
i tried to did it but did not able to append the output to single variable.....
Please Help Bulk

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, I ran into this error message while working on Code 2.1.0 in Firefox, and I landed here. My problem was that my code had an error or warning which was generated in a sub view. Because my /application/config/config.php file had this line

```
$config['compress_output'] = TRUE;
```

I received the same error message as the question author. I changed that line

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
```

Then, I was able to see the **real** error I was dealing with. Hope this helps someone!